# Converting button Icon back to Image

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I want to extract/read the button icon image as a Flex image component, then apply transform filters to it to make it black/white and then apply image as an icon to another button.
Any ideas how I could do that?
So far I can get the icon out as an Object by doing this:

```
var iconImg:Object = myBtn.getStyle("icon");
```

Not sure how to convert that Object to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iconImage Object is type of DisplayObject. So you can draw in onto a BitmapData object then apply transforms to at and set other button's 'icon' style to this new transformed object.

Comment: Only difference is I had to use:
var iconImg:DisplayObject = myBtn.getChildByName("icon");